# RadSpreadsheet Cell Values for DateTime returning Number values (Telerik)

Tags: telerik, spreadsheet

I have a CSV file with Dates ("MM/DD/YYYY"). I wish to parse these values within the active worksheet as string values, but they're converted to number format (i.e. "22532"). I'm unable to get these values in the original string format.

```
CellSelection selection = sheet.Cells[0, 0];
ICellValue value = selection.GetValue().Value;
```

Is it possible to ensure all cell values are in String format, representing exactly how they are in a CSV file?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code:

```
CellSelection selection = sheet.Cells[0, 0];
string value = selection.GetValue().Value.GetResultValueAsString(new CellValueFormat("mm/d/yyyy"));
```

This will return a string formatted as a date. In the case with "22532" the result will be "09/8/1961".

Answer (score 0):

This is not the exact answer you are looking for, but you can convert the int value to a datetime with the following code:

```
 public static DateTime FromExcelSerialDate(this int serialDate)
 {
     if (serialDate > 59) serialDate -= 1; //Excel/Lotus 2/29/1900 bug   
     return new DateTime(1899, 12, 31).AddDays(serialDate);
 }
```